# Polygon border intersections

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

I have several polygons, which intersect/overlap each other. I only consider the border of the polygons now, the inside is irrelevant.

Is there a well-known algorithm to divide the intersecting polygon borders into new polygons, which do not intersect (but are adjacent)?

Example: A David-Star ✡ can be seen as two intersecting triangles (one pointing up, one pointing down). I am looking for an algorithm to divide the polygons into six triangles and one hexagon in the middle. Adjacent polygons may *not* be merged here.

I have looked for an algorithm for this, but failed. Maybe I do not know the correct keyword to look it up?

Comment: googling "polygon intersection algorithm" seems to give a lot of nice stuff

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I primarily find algorithms there which determine the intersecting area of two polygons, which is not exactly what I am looking for

Comment: I thought sth like this returns a polygon, not an area
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm